# How to handle multiple request in Java servlet

Tags: java, servlets

I have a UI where there is HTML table with input fields as cells and some input field outside the HTML table, so there I am entering data and on click of save saving data into my data base using `servlets`

It is working fine when only one user is using it at a time but causing issue when two user clicks save at same time

**What I am doing is:**

- After Clicking on save I am calling my `servlet` class where I have written a code to insert the data into DB
- So in my `servlet` class firstly I am running a query to get max+1 no. of a column from db and then saving it and using that value  further in my  insert query

**Issue I am facing is:**

- When two user clicks save on same time, the query which is to get max+1 runs and the next query which is to insert data runs but the second one throws error as `java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Duplicate entry '2' for key 'PRIMARY'`  because that one is primary key column in db and it can't be duplicate
- but why it is taking only `2` like only one no when two user has clicked save button it should take 2,3 I think Here I am not handling the multiple request in my `servlet` which I don't even know how to handle, I have googled a lot and read there that servlets it self manages the multiple processing at one time
- So my issue is I want to insert data into my db when multiple user clicks save button at single time, if there are two user clicking save at same time it is causing issue

**My code**

```
int grnNo;
Connection con = null;
Statement statement = null;

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

}

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    String[] itemCode = request.getParameterValues("itemCodetd");
    String[] unitCode = request.getParameterValues("unittd");

    try {
        con = DBConnection.createConnection();
        statement = con.createStatement();

        String grnNoSql = "select max(GRNNUMBER)+1 as GRNNo from egoodsreceived";
        ResultSet resultSet1 = statement.executeQuery(grnNoSql);

        while (resultSet1.next()) {
            int grnNoLocal = resultSet1.getInt("GRNNo");

            if (grnNo != 0) {
                grnNo = grnNoLocal;
                System.out.println("in if  :" + grnNo);
            } else {
                grnNo = 1;
                System.out.println("in else  :" + grnNo);
            }

        }

        String query1 = "query to insert data";

        PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(query1);

        for (int i = 0; i < itemCode.length; i++) {
            if (itemCode[i] != "") {
                System.out.println("in for :" + grnNo);
                ps.setInt(1, grnNo);
                ps.setString(2, itemCode[i]);
                ps.setString(3, unitCode[i]);

                ps.addBatch();
            }
        }

        ps.executeBatch(); // here getting erro as duplicate primary key

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println("SQL EXCPTION   91");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    doGet(request, response);
}
```

Comment: Your database will provide a mechanism to generate IDs either via Sequence or 'Identity' column type therefore avoiding such issues. What database are you using?

Comment: @AlanHay I am using MySql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are using instance variables in servlets. There is only a single instance of each servlet in the JVM, so concurrent requests will attempt to use the same variable at the same time.

Refactor `grnNo`, `con` and `statement` to local variables, then wrap the select and insert into a single transaction.

Comment: you are saying that I should move all the global variables to doPost(local)?

Comment: Move it to `protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)`

Comment: You can make `grnNo` a local variable but there is still a race condition. Unless you want to synchronize the Java code then you need to delegate to the database for ID generation.

Comment: A transaction is not going to help you here. You would need to synchronize the Java code.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why are you trying to increment and set the id manually?

Comment: You can keep that in an instance variable. So define `int count;` at instance level, than in doPost() call `System.out.println(++count);`

Comment: This solution is not thread safe. Multiple threads can read the same max value from the database betwen updates.

Answer (score 1):

You should define the column to use MySQL's auto increment functionality:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/example-auto-increment.html

```
CREATE TABLE X(
     id MEDIUMINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
     PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

You need not then specify the column or its value in the insert statement: the value will then be automatically assigned by the database.

The other answer makes a valid point about thread safety with instance variables in Servlets however, without adding a synchronized block, **making `grnNo` a local variable does not address the issue**:

```
//Thread T1 executes the below and get the next val
//before T1 has written its changes, T2 executes the below and gets the next val
String grnNoSql = "select max(GRNNUMBER)+1 as GRNNo from egoodsreceived";
```

If you need  the generated identifier in the application after the insert then you can use the `getGeneratedKeys()` method of java.sql.statement:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#getGeneratedKeys()

Comment: That is an alternate  answer to it I have to do it this way

Comment: Sorry but have updated to show that without a synchronization block then making the variable local is not going to work. This is how every application does it and there is no good reason to deviate from that.

Comment: hey there is no need to use `getGeneratedKeys()` That is just a no which not auto incriment, can you show me an example releated to my code

Comment: I have given you the answer to your problem. I'm not sure what else you need.

Comment: 1. Alter your database  column to be auto-increment and, 2. alter your SQL insert so it doesn't include the id field. That's it.

Comment: but that I can't do I can't alter the DB tables, why the above answer is not working as I have putted all in my `doPost`  made them local?

Comment: As I have clearly explained you can still have a race condition. You will need to synchronize around the database access to prevent this although that will obviously create a point of contention . http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-concurrency/synchronized.html  and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19509543/how-we-can-make-servlet-synchronized

Comment: in the above link it says synchronizing the servlets is not a good approach

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197158/discussion-between-manish-thakur-and-alan-hay).

Comment: Which is why you let the database handle it. So you take my solution, or you synchronize the code. **These are the 2 options available to you to handle your issue.** Choose one.